# Compress Makefile Intermediates (Two ways to create same target)

Tags: makefile, compression, gzip

I have a Makefile I'm currently using for purposes other than compiling. Instead of deleting intermediate files, I'd like to keep them, but gzip them, and then later have Makefile detect that an intermediate file exists and instead of recomputing it, simply unzip it.

Let's suppose I have target **target.txt** that depends on an intermediate file called **intermediate.txt**, which itself depends on **prereq.txt**. So something like:

```
target.txt: intermediate.txt
intermediate.txt: prereq.txt
```

Now by default Make deletes the intermediate file, but we can disable that. But let's say that both computing *intermediate.txt* takes a long time, so I'll disable automatic deletion of it. But what if file *intermediate.txt* is also very large, so I'd like to compress it (gzip) to **intermediate.txt.gz**. Instead of recomputing the file, I'd like Make to unzip the existing zipped file, so *gunzip intermediate.txt.gz*.

The larger question I suppose I'm asking is I have two ways of making a target, based on two different dependencies. I'd like Make to execute the rule that has the prerequisite that exists, and ignore the other rule, but perhaps delete the zipped version and recompute it only if the prerequisite to the intermediate has a newer timestamp. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU Make, you can do this with pattern rules (tac is used to represent whatever processing you're doing):

```
%.txt: %.i.txt
    tac $^ > $@               #make .txt file the normal way
    gzip $^                   #gzip the intermediate file

%.txt: %.i.txt.gz
    gunzip < $^ | tac > $@    #make .txt by streaming in the gzipped intermediate

%.i.txt: %.p.txt
    tac $^ > $@               #make the intermediate file from the prereq
```

This works for pattern rules because if the `.i.txt` file is not found, Make falls through to the next pattern and looks for the `.i.txt.gz` version. This does not work for explicit rules, because later rules simply replace earlier rules.

Comment: Ah thanks! This works to a point. However, when I have two levels of zipped intermediates, I need to make the zipped version of one dependent on the zipped version of the other, in order to force it to rerun it all.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you do NOT want to just uncompress the .gz version if prereq.txt is newer than the gzipped file.  In that case, I would tend to just use shell tests to store off and restore the gzipped file and not get make directly involved:

```
target.txt: intermediate.txt
        ...same as it ever was ....

intermediate.txt: prereq.txt
        if [ $@.gz -nt $< ]; then      \
            gunzip <$@.gz >$@;         \
        else                           \
            whatever >$@ <$<;          \
            gzip <$@ >$@.gz;           \
        fi
```

where 'whatever' is the command that creates intermediate.txt from prereq.txt